# Why are the Line2D objects that are supposed to be contained by a matplotlib Axis showing up as empty?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axes

The figure plots just fine, but I can't access the Line2D objects.

Example code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

df=pd.DataFrame({"col1":np.random.rand(10), "col2":np.random.rand(10)})

fig=pyplot.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax=df.plot(kind="scatter", x="col1", y="col2", ax=ax)
ax.lines # the result is an empty list.
fig.show()
```

Also `ax.get_lines()` gives the same result, i.e. no lines. The same thing happens when I plot directly with `ax.scatter(...)`.

Comment: In my opinion `scatter` does not produce a line. Have a look at what `ax.scatter()` returns.

Comment: Maybe you want to tell what you think you need `lines` for in case you do not actually plot any lines in the figure. The `scatter` is in `ax.collections`.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and @Thomas Kühn. I was trying to access the data plotted in the scatterplot. Yes, `ax.collections` is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot 
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

df=pd.DataFrame({"col1":np.random.rand(10), "col2":np.random.rand(10)})

fig=pyplot.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax=df.plot(kind="scatter", x="col1", y="col2", ax=ax)
line = Line2D(df["col1"],df["col2"]) #create the lines with Line2D 
ax.add_line(line) #add the lines to fig
fig.show()
```

This returns [image]

Comment: I'm not trying to plot the lines. I'm trying to access the data that was plotted in the scatterplot. Other comments have answered the question.